# Restful API calls from AngularJS and Query string

Tags: javascript, angularjs, express

I am currently working on a web app where i have edit functionality.

Currently i build a page with a list of records which all contain the id.

So when i click on the edit button it does the following:

```
 $state.go('editCustomer', { customerObj: customer });
```

This then directs to the edit page which shows the correct record and prepoulates the data which is fine.

However I wanted to do in a way where i click the edit button and it creates a url similar to the following: /customer?id=12345

When the edit pages loads it would then grab the id from the query string and call the get using $resource.

So my question is how would i be able to do this? And would i need to change the api routing on the server side to accomodate this as currently is as follows for the get

```
router.get('/:id', controller.show);
```

Any help would be great

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [ui-sref](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.directive:ui-sref):

```
<a ui-sref="editCustomer({ id: customer.id })">Edit</a>
```

This will create the correct URL for the route (something like: `/customer/12345`).

This works for a route like this:

```
$stateProvider
  .state('editCustomer', {
    url: '/customer/:id',
    // etc ...
  });
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. WIll give this a shot but have read up on it and should do the trick